# Is it possible to create user defined functions in Tableau? If yes, what coding language it uses?

Tags: function, tableau-api, defined

Tableau has many in-built functions but if I want to create my own functions and save it, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It is a good question.

Comment: This would be really useful IMO.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create functions in Tableau, you can only mix and use the functions available to create your own methods/logic. Personally, I use [Google Keep](https://www.google.com/keep/) to store any snippets (from real code to Tableau functions) that I believe will be used later.

If you need to heavily manipulate your data, Tableau recommends to do it in the database level (i.e. using custom SQL queries) or using a data blending/cleaning tool (an opensource that comes to mind is [Pentaho Data Integration](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/)).